# Replace all strings in file, using wildcards in the substitution

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm using sed in bash to try replace all strings matching:

```
compile 'com.test.*:*'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.test.*:+'
```

Where * is a wildcard.

My file looks like this, it's called moo.txt:

```
compile 'com.test.common:4.0.1'
compile 'com.test.streaming:5.0.10'
compile 'com.test.ui:1.0.7'
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
compile 'com.test.common:+'
compile 'com.test.streaming:+'
compile 'com.test.ui:+'
```

I've tried to use sed like:

```
sed -i -- "s/compile \'com.test.*:.*\'/compile \'com.test.*:+\'/g" moo.txt
```

But this makes the file look like:

```
compile 'com.test.*:+'
compile 'com.test.*:+'
compile 'com.test.*:+'
```

Any ideas how to use the wildcard in the substitute field properly?

Comment: Look up capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching things after `com.test` but you don't print them back properly.

So you are indeed matching something, only that you are not printing it back. Instead, you are printing a literal `.*`:

```
sed "s/compile \'com.test.*:.*\'/compile \'com.test.*:+\'/g"
#                        ^^                        ^^
#                match this                  print back? NO
```

To do so, capture the pattern and print it back using a backreference.

```
sed -E "s/compile 'com.test(.*):.*'/compile 'com.test\1:+'/g"
#                          ^^^^                      ^^
#                    catch this             print back! now YES!
```

See we are repeating "compile..." too much? This means that we can extend the capture to the very beginning of the line, since the backreference will print all of it back:

```
sed -E "s/^(compile 'com.test.*):.*'/\1:+'/g"
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
#           capture all of this      print it back
```

Note the usage of `-E` to allow `sed` capture groups with just `(...)`. If we didn't use `-E`, we should do `\(...\)`.

Note also that you were escaping single quotes, while it is not necessary since you are inside double quotes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this worked. Is it possible to add many backreferences such that gives you \1 and \2 etc?

Comment: @user2010496 of course! You can use up to 9. Check for example `echo "hello how are" | sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)/\3 _ \2 _ \1/'`.

Comment: This is so beautiful!

Comment: If you use `-E` instead of `-r` it'll work on BSD sed as well as newer versions of GNU sed. `-r` only works on GNU sed and was just a bad idea for an argument name (How do you enable EREs in various tools? You use GNU `grep -E`, BSD `sed -E` and GNU `sed -r`? Come on...).

Comment: @EdMorton Newer versions of BSD `sed` support both flags, but [the `-E` flag will be standardized](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E "s/[^:]+$/+'/" moo.txt 
compile 'com.test.common:+'
compile 'com.test.streaming:+'
compile 'com.test.ui:+'
```

- `[^:]+$` matches all characters other than `:` at end of line
- If hex escapes are allowed, use `sed -E 's/[^:]+$/+\x27/'` to avoid possibility of shell interpretation when using double quotes

To qualify only lines have `compile 'com.test` at start of line

```
sed -E "/^compile 'com.test/ s/[^:]+$/+'/" moo.txt
```